# UIAppearance edge insets

Tags: ios, swift, styling, uiappearance

I have a `UIView` subclass which I use in my app (And is in a 3rd party library) for displaying toast notifications. I want to modify this slightly for another app I'm working on and so I'm adding styling properties via `UIAppearance`. I have some working, but some of them refuse to work properly!

```
/// The visible duration of the toast view
@objc public dynamic var visibleDuration: CGFloat = 2.0

/// The margins to apply around the toast view
@objc public dynamic var margins: UIEdgeInsets = .zero
```

`visibleDuration` works fine here, and is set by `ToastView.appearance().visibleDuration = 6` but `margins` is never non-zero! Is there something special I need to do here to support setting a `UIEdgeInsets` via `UIAppearance`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was being correctly set, but due to the nature of my class the point at which I was trying to lay out my view using them they weren't available as their `UIAppearance` values. It seems like the view needs to be added to the window hierarchy before the values are updated to reflect their `UIAppearance` values! Moving around my layout code to occur after adding to the window fixed this!